# Como acessar nó filho no Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, realtime-database

Eu tenho a seguinte árvore no Firebase:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para acessar para poder listar os dados que estão dentro do nó "furos"?

Estou usando o seguinte método de listagem de dados:

```
public void recuperaFuros(){
    DatabaseReference furosRef = firebaseRef
            .child(idUsuario.toString())
            .child("vhykFsTJMhaCd6jkBd3oXpmYoiH2Thu Jan 10 22:54:24 GMT-02:00 2019")
             .child("furos")
            .child("Thu Jan 10 22:54:51 GMT-02:00 2019");

    furosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            furos.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                furos.add(ds.getValue(Furo.class));

                //System.out.println("PROJETO" + ds.getValue());
            }
            adapterFuros.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

porém, meu retorno está sendo:

```
 Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type geoapp.cursoandroid.com.geoapp.model.Furo
```

na linha

```
furos.add(ds.getValue(Furo.class));
```

Minhas regras estão assim:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read" : true,
      ".write" : true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que,  no laço de repetição `for`, a cada iteração ele pega uma propriedade do objeto, então o valor de `ds.getValue` é o valor da propriedade `alvoFuro`, ou seja, "alv"

Tente remover a última chamada ao método `child`

```
//...
DatabaseReference furosRef = firebaseRef
        .child(idUsuario.toString())
        .child("vhykFsTJMhaCd6jkBd3oXpmYoiH2Thu Jan 10 22:54:24 GMT-02:00 2019")
         .child("furos");

furosRef.addValueEventListener(//...
```

Comment: O erro desapareceu, porém, meu recycler não trás os dados

Comment: Se eu apago a linha que dá erro e debugo com o System.out.println(ds.getValue) ele trás meus dados

Comment: Então esse problema foi resolvido e você pode aceitar a resposta. Faça outra pergunta se não conseguir resolver o outro problema!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, primeiramente você deve estruturar melhor o seu BD.

Ao invés de usar um Id seguido da hora da solicitação, tente a seguinte saida:

idUsuario
(idProjeto) 
// Você vai setar com 
myRef.child("Usuarios").child(user.getUid()).push().child("Timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
//Demais dados

O push fará que você tenha um ID único. E o timestamp logo abaxo, você substitui pela "dataHoraCadastro". 
O timeStamp será um dado que você conseguirá converter facilmente quando necessário. Ao invés de tratar essa hora e data que você está utilizando. O TimeStamp te dá data completa, até os milisegundos.

//Dentro de furos, você fará a mesma coisa. Ao invez de ser a data completa como id, você pode usar o push() ou o timestamp.

myRef.child("Usuarios").child(user.getUid()).push().child("furos).child("Timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
//Demais DAdos
E para evitar redundância na parte "dataHoraCadastro", você pode usar no firebase, o datasnapsho.getKey(). (Que ao invés de pegar o dado, você terá acesso a chave, que seria seu Timestamp, ou data, se preferir manter).

```
public void recuperaFuros(){
    DatabaseReference furosRef = firebaseRef
            .child(idUsuario.toString())
            .child("vhykFsTJMhaCd6jkBd3oXpmYoiH2Thu Jan 10 22:54:24 GMT-02:00 2019")
             .child("furos")
            .child("Thu Jan 10 22:54:51 GMT-02:00 2019");

    furosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            furos.clear();
           if(dataSnapshot.exist())`{
                furos.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Furo.class));
}
                //System.out.println("PROJETO" + ds.getValue());
            }
            adapterFuros.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

// Você está usando o forEach para pegar dados únicos. Se a classe estiver com as mesmas variáveis que estão no BD, elas serão atribuídas normalmente.